# How to access selected record column value in nested sub-datasheet form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I spend half day to figure out how to access value in nested datasheet form record.
Please, take a look at image below.
I have dblClick event on "SID" column cell. It's field name is "txtSID".
I need to grab that value (in picture "20") and pass it in VBA SQL.
There is some trick with datasheets. Looks like they has no control name or something.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found solution. """ & Me![txtSID] & """ does the thing.

```
Private Sub txtSID_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
Dim SQL As String

SQL = "INSERT INTO documents (stakeholder_id, document_type_id, status_id) VALUES (""" & Me![txtSID] & """, 1, 1);"

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```